# Javascript form is not able to submit as expected on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I have a function that creates a form in javascript and submits it. It works as expected in Safari, Chrome, FF, & Opera but not IE 10.

When the from submits the browser is not pointed to the url in the action attribute in IE. I'm sure this is lame but I can't find the problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function checkout() {
    var myDoc = 'some xml data to send'
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute( "method", "POST" );
    form.setAttribute( "action", "http://domain.com/script.php" );
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "name", "myField" );
    hiddenField.setAttribute( "value", myDoc );
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    form.submit();
}
```

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: What happened here ? I answer the question. Somebody comes long after and gives the same answer (minus the fact it's a IE specific thing) and is accepted ?

Answer (score 3):

On Internet Explorer you have to append the form to the document (I don't know if it's a bug or a feature).

Simply do

```
form.style.display = 'none'; // useful if you're targeting another window
document.body.appendChild(form);
```

Comment: Have an upvote on me mate. Its unfortunate but the OP is quite new, he just accepted whichever answer shows up closer to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the form, but you're not appending it to the document.

Add

document.documentElement.appendChild(form);

just before

form.submit();